# Unable to properly call sqlcmd from powershell

Tags: sql, powershell, sqlcmd

I had this sqlcmd snippet working in batch but when I converted to powershell, it broke. This is what I am attempting to call using powershell

```
Sqlcmd -S localhost\instance -d database -U username -P password -i "sqlQuery.sql" -s "," > \sqlOutput.csv -I -W -k
```

I tried invoke-sqlcmd but i get the error "The term 'invoke-sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

In regards to the comment below, I have loaded the snapins required. This did help but I am now getting this error. "Invoke-sqlcmd : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 's' is ambiguous.

If I put it in single quotes...

```
invoke-Sqlcmd '-S localhost\instance -d database -U username -P password -i "sqlQuery.sql" -s "," > \sqlOutput.csv -I -W -k'
```

I get the error "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connectiong to sql server. Which doesn't make sense to me as the same credentials i am using here (on the same box) work when called from batch.

Comment: To call Invoke-Sqlcmd you have to have loaded the SQL snapin.

Comment: The parameters of sqlcmd.exe and invoke-sqlcmd are not the same. see help invoke-sqlcmd -full for a list of parameters and example usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first call sqlps.exe from powershell or command prompt (assuming you have the SQL Server snap-ins for Powershell installed).

Once you do that, execute `get-help Invoke-Sqlcmd` to find your way around.

To your question, its not -S, but -ServerInstance

```
 PS SQLSERVER:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "srvrName" -Database "master" -Username "user123" -Password "x$34fth" 
-InputFile "C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\test.sql" | Out-File "C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\out.txt"
```

You can also use the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281962%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) documentation

Answer (score 0):

Goto

- Windows Explorer 
- Right Click Computer 
- Properties 
- Advanced System Settings 
- Environment Variables

Make sure PSModulePath is set with following string.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules`